# Children's fantasy book about a girl traveling to another world

Tags: story-identification, magic, spells

I’ve been searching for this children’s book for literally over 25 years. I was probably about 10 years old when I visited the Orem Library (Utah) 1993 ish. I include the place on the off chance it could be a local book. The librarian gave me this book telling me that I would probably love it. I read it, loved it, and that’s what got me started in my love of reading! I have since tried to find it with absolutely no luck. Here I will dedicate a post in the hopes that someone, somewhere will know what I am talking about. Here are the few details I know about the plot.

-Main character is a young girl.
-Girl goes to live with her aunts (might be good friends of parents and not relatives)
-Things seem normal except the girl is forbidden to read from a certain book the aunts have.
-One day the aunts get kidnapped and the girl must go into another world to find them.
-The girl has a companion that is a little dwarf, gnome, or other weird creature.
-As the girl progresses in her journey she learns new spells that help her progress.
-At one point the girl must get a new guide given to her by the bad guy (maybe) but she knows a spell that forces her old companion to tell the truth if the new guy is trustworthy so she gets a different one.

Comment: Also posted about 5-6 years ago at https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/12047366-children-s-fantasy-girl-goes-to-live-w-aunts-she-is-forbidden-to-read. For the record, there's no issue with crossposting (except posting at the time time to multiple SEs the same question), but I like to note it because it can help people who see it in the search results and think they have an answer until they see it's the same question.

Comment: Some similar stories mentioned in https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/1638365-solved-girl-has-to-move-in-with-her-aunts-finds-out-they-are-magica. I haven't had a chance to follow up on anything but the one that turned out to be the answer (which would not be the answer here).